# Unable to install CentOS in virtualBox in MacOS

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I am not able to install CentOS 7 in VirtualBox on MacOS (1.7 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7) because of some unknown reasons. I am getting an error message as shown below after setting up the iso file before starting the installation :

Failed to run unattended guest installation.

Unknown guest OS major version '7'.

Result Code:NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005)

Component: UnattendedWrap

Interface: Unattended {6f89464f-7773-436a-a4df-592e4e537fa0}

And after I start the installation, it is interrupted saying an unknown error has occurred as shown below.
[image]

Could someone please help me with this?